# I cannot install kivy for python 3.6 on os x in a Virtualenv

Tags: kivy, virtualenv, python-3.6

When I try to install (using homebrew) kivy for python 3.6 in a virtualenv:

(vs36) MacBook-Pro-de-Juan:Environments juancarlos1$ python
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

certifi (2017.11.5)
chardet (3.0.4)
cycler (0.10.0)
Cython (0.26.1)
docutils (0.14)
idna (2.6)
Kivy-Garden (0.1.4)
lxml (4.1.1)
matplotlib (2.1.1)
numpy (1.14.0)
pip (9.0.1)
Pygments (2.2.0)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
python-docx (0.8.6)
pytz (2017.3)
requests (2.18.4)
scipy (1.0.0)
setuptools (38.4.0)
six (1.11.0)
urllib3 (1.22)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
wheel (0.30.0)

I get the following problem (I have no problems running kivy for python 2.7 not using virtualen) when I requirements using homebrew following kivy documentation:

$ brew install pkg-config sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer

I get these warning:
Warning: pkg-config 0.29.2 is already installed
Warning: sdl2 2.0.7 is already installed
Warning: sdl2_image 2.0.2 is already installed
Warning: sdl2_ttf 2.0.14 is already installed
Warning: sdl2_mixer 2.0.2_3 is already installed
Warning: gstreamer 1.12.4 is already installed

After I install kivy with pip:
$ pip install kivy

and then generate a lot of warnings like this:

1 warning generated.
  /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/private/var/folders/zy/q412_r2s2258llsbt7c9fgwh0000gp/T/pip-build-01ys1bww/kivy/kivy/graphics/context_instructions.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/kivy/graphics/context_instructions.cpython-36m-darwin.so -F/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -lm

and finallly failed:

```
3 errors generated.
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/Users/juancarlos1/Environments/vs36/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/zy/q412_r2s2258llsbt7c9fgwh0000gp/T/pip-build-01ys1bww/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zy/q412_r2s2258llsbt7c9fgwh0000gp/T/pip-x7xb41xw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/juancarlos1/Environments/vs36/bin/../include/site/python3.6/kivy" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zy/q412_r2s2258llsbt7c9fgwh0000gp/T/pip-build-01ys1bww/kivy/

Comment: please read [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  we can't help you without being able to reproduce

Comment: Successfully installed Kivy-1.10.1.dev0 I try this:                                        
pip install --verbose https://github.com/kivy/kivy/zipball/master